# Can I run publish Microsoft PowerApps apps on PlayStore and App Store?

Tags: ios, google-play, powerapps, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

When I develop an app using Microsoft PowerApp... Can I publish on Google Play Store and Apple App Store?  And also the Huawei App Gallery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say no. The applications built with PowerApps are part of the Power Platform. Therefore, you can only run your application inside the official [PowerApp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/mobile/run-powerapps-on-mobile). You cannot publish it on Huawei AppGallery, AppStore, or PlayStore.

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot be released to AppGallery.

You may consider deploy your app as webapps. Or according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/mobile/run-powerapps-on-mobile#pin-to-home), pin the apps to the home screen of the device for quick access.

Answer (score 2):

No. PowerApps only runs in the context of the tenant. Of course, you can install PowerApps on any smartphone, then authenticate with the tenant credentials and run any PowerApp published to that user account.

But you cannot download a PowerApp as a stand-alone app via Apple or Google stores.

Comment: Even though this is probably not what you want to hear, this is the correct answer to your question.